# bedroom door will not close after hinges werre changed

Tags: doors

my son kicked his bedroom from the inside and the hinges were bent forward. I changed the hinges and now the door doesn't close there is a 1/4 in between the hinges when you close the door. I just try to do things myself but I wanted to see if anyone has some suggestions thank you Kay South

Comment: That much force could have knocked the Door Jamb out of whack. ( whack is a technical term for alignment, plumb, level. )

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the hinge plates are sitting in the recessed hinge seats & are flush to the door jamb & the door edge. Another cause could be that 1 or more hinges are upside down. Make sure the removable pin is on top or the hinges won't close. Also, you may need longer or thicker screws as the screw holes may not be holding tightly any longer.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me and I figured it out. One of the three hinges wasn't on right. It was not upside down, since the pin was at the top.  So if you hold a hinge, they flap in and out. Mine was flapping the wrong way, even though it was upright. The brand on the hinges should be facing inward, when it's up. Or if you're holding it flat on your hand the brand should be on top. So try installing it while flapped the opposite way. Check all the hinges on the door and make sure they're all facing the same way when flapped.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 1):

If the hinge plates aren't flat  against each other they may be bent from the door being forced closed. Remove the hinge with the 1/4 inch gap to see if it closes completely. Hammer them together if not and re-install.  Make certain the hinges are exactly in the door and jamb mortises (recess for the hinge).

It may also be the strike plate is not in-line with the door catch.